# python.sty on TeX Live 2013 - Forbidden to open for writing error

Tags: texlive, windows, python

I have a fresh install of TeX Live 2013 and am attempting to compile a file using the python package. Here is the relevant portion of the file

```
\begin{python}
print 'hi'
\end{python}
```

I've compiled successfully on my linux machine with TeX Live 2013, but cannot get my windows 7 machine to compile successfully. When I run `latex --shell-escape pytest.tex` I get an error which begins with

```
pytest.py: Forbidden to open for writing
! I can't write on file `pytest.py'.
\@python ...mediate \openout \@out =\@outname .py
                                                   \newlinechar ='15 \begingr...
```

Can anyone help me fix this so I can compile latex documents using python.sty on my windows machine?

## Update

So I'm pretty certain the issue has to do with permissions. If that is the case it would be really great if there were a few easy tests I could run to determine why \write18 cannot open files for writing / what it is trying to do. I've seen some problems from searching that were related to the TEXMFOUTPUT environment variable, but I don't know (1) what to set as the value of TEXMFOUTPUT in order to make sure that these temporary python files are created in the current working directory and (2) if setting TEXMFOUTPUT would have anything to do with these \write18 permission problems.

Ok, one new piece of information: So, I've created a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}

\begin{python}
print 'hi'
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

When compiled after the `! I can't write on file pytest1.py' It says (Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit; default file extension is '.tex' Is this error because write18 can only write to a .tex file?

At the beginning of the compile on the second line it just says ` \write18 enabled'. So it is not running with restricted \write18. I feel like I am really close to fixing this.

## Solved

The comment [python.sty on TeX Live 2013 - Forbidden to open for writing error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141229/python-sty-on-tex-live-2013-forbidden-to-open-for-writing-error#comment319115_141229) was exactly right. I had .py listed in my PATHEXT environment variable. Removing it allowed the file to compile without error.

Just read meta.tex.SE and will credit JosephWright once answer is up.

Comment: This seems like a problem with permissions. Are you administrator on the machine? Are you running TeX from the command prompt, or from within an editor? Run either (`cmd` or your editor) as administrator and try again.

Comment: I agree. I am administrator and can either call tex from cygwin's command line or from emacs (C-c C-c). I've tried both and get the same error...

Comment: On Windows systems you can't use `\write` to create any executable file types (`.bat` is the common one). Do you have `.py` set up to be associated with Pyhton and runnable? If so, you'll need to write to a different name then use `write18` to rename to `.py`.

Comment: @JosephWright I believe that python.sty already takes care of the issue of writing executable types. My file is named pytest.tex, when latex compiles it writes to pytest.py, which is then called by python. I won't be back to my home pc until this evening, and will check the .py file associations.

Comment: @NickH Risky using the same name for all files!

Comment: @JosephWright it's not hard to modify python.sty so that it writes on file names like `filename1.py' instead of simply filename.py but I have the same write issue either way. There are a few versions I've tried, all have this write error on my windows machine.

Comment: @NickH: You still haven't answered whether `.py` files are made executable on your system. If they are, then write to `.pyc` and then run a script as part of the compilation that renames it. Such automation is not difficult in TeXnicCenter.

Comment: @Werner Sorry, just updated post. You're right. and Joseph's comment about executables was exactly the issue -- I didn't quite understand how to check when I read the comment last night. But when looking at the environment variables and seeing .py in the PATHEXT along with .exe made me realize that I needed to remove .py from PATHEXT. So problem is solved, that was the issue. Can I award an answer to a comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, TeX systems deliberately disable writing of executable file types (which are extension-based) *via* `\write` operations. Thus you cannot create a file called `foo.py` if `.py` files are set up to be executable. The common case for this problem is batch (`.bat`) files, which are plain text but executable without any add-ons and thus 'forbidden'. With `\write18` enabled, the easiest approach is to write to an alternative file name then use the shell escape to rename the file, which is allowed as `\write18` is 'do whatever you want'.