# Writing environments out to files and prepending/appending additional code

Tags: verbatim, shell-escape

I am using the following code snippet to write environments out to files and run arbitrary commands (like `python` or `Rscript`). It works quite nice however I would like to write something to the file before and after I insert the stuff from the enviroment there:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{Rtest}[1]%
  {\xdef\d@tn@me{#1}%
  % \xdef\r@ncmd{Rscript #1.R > #1.Rlog}% uncomment to run command on file
  \typeout{Writing file #1}\VerbatimOut{#1.R}% 
  }
  {\endVerbatimOut %
 \toks0{\immediate\write18}%
 %\expandafter\toks\expandafter1\expandafter{\r@ncmd}% uncomment to run command on file
 %\edef\d@r@ncmd{\the\toks0{\the\toks1}}\d@r@ncmd % uncomment to run command on file
 \input{\d@tn@me.R}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame[containsverbatim]{

\begin{Rtest}{hello}
Hallo Welt 
\end{Rtest}

}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is to have an environment like the following:

```
\begin{Rtest}{hello}{beforecode}{aftercode}
Hallo Welt 
\end{Rtest}
```

that results in `hello.R` looking like this:

```
beforecode
Hallo Welt
aftercode
```

How can I modify the code above to accomplish this?

Comment: Not an answer to the question; but `\immediate\write18{\r@ncmd}` is much easier than that long series of commands: `\r@ncmd` has been defined by `\xdef`, so it has survived full expansion so it can go as argument to `\write`.

Comment: Use `\begin{frame}[fragile]...\end{frame}` and not `\frame{...}`.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2574/27635) of Ulrike Fischer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{environ}

\newwrite\myexport

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{Rtest}[3]{%
\immediate\openout\myexport=#1.R%
\toks@={#2}%
\immediate\write\myexport{\the\toks@}%
\toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}%
\immediate\write\myexport{\the\toks@}%
\toks@={#3}%
\immediate\write\myexport{\the\toks@}%
\immediate\closeout\myexport%
\input{#1.R}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frame[containsverbatim]{

\begin{Rtest}{hello}{beforecode}{aftercode}
Hallo Welt
\end{Rtest}

}

\end{document}
```

Contents of `hello.R`

```
beforecode
Hallo Welt
aftercode
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This will tokenize the contents of `Rtest`, losing the possibility of doing `verbatim`; for instance, line breaks will be lost.

Comment: @egreg I know, but I'm not sure about what has to be the contents of the `.R` file and anyway, I can't do any better...

Comment: `Rtest` will contain arbitrary R or Python code, line breaks must remain as they are as they may have a special meaning.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution will not read the input (content environment) verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Customizing `fancyvrb`'s `VerbatimOut` might be the simplest approach. This should give you a good starting point for additional customization.

I wrote this for Python since I don't have an R installation handy.  The test environment takes the base name of the script, the before code, and the after code, in addition to an optional argument that specifies whether the code is executed. If code is executed, the output is brought in verbatim. You should be able to customize this easily to get whatever you need.

This assumes that the before code and after code are single lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\VerbatimOutPlus{\FV@Environment{}{VerbatimOutPlus}}

% Write #2 before and #3 after environment contents
\def\FVB@VerbatimOutPlus#1#2#3{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \FV@UseKeyValues
    \FV@DefineWhiteSpace
    \def\FV@Space{\space}%
    \FV@DefineTabOut
    \def\FV@ProcessLine{\immediate\write\FV@OutFile}%
    \immediate\openout\FV@OutFile #1\relax
    % Added next 2 lines
    \immediate\write\FV@OutFile{#2}%
    \def\FV@appendline{#3}%
    \let\FV@FontScanPrep\relax
    \let\@noligs\relax
    \FV@Scan}

\def\FVE@VerbatimOutPlus{%
  % Added next line
  \immediate\write\FV@OutFile{\FV@appendline}%
  \immediate\closeout\FV@OutFile\endgroup\@esphack}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbatimOutPlus}{VerbatimOutPlus}{}

\newenvironment{PYtest}[4][]%
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
    \def\FV@run@opts{#1}%
    \def\FV@Plus@outfilename{#2.py}%
    \begin{VerbatimOutPlus}{#2.py}{#3}{#4}}%
  {\end{VerbatimOutPlus}%
    \VerbatimInput{\FV@Plus@outfilename}%
    \ifdefstring{\FV@run@opts}{run}{%
      \hrule
      \immediate\write18{python \FV@Plus@outfilename\space> \FV@Plus@outfilename log}%
      \VerbatimInput{\FV@Plus@outfilename log}}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
\begin{PYtest}[run]{hello}{'''beforecode'''}{'''aftercode'''}
print('Text')
\end{PYtest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am receiving an error message with your code: `! I can't write on file `hello.py'.`

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen That looks like a permissions issue. Probably the same as [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141229/python-sty-on-tex-live-2013-forbidden-to-open-for-writing-error) if you are on Windows.