# xsim file suffixes

Tags: verbatim, latex3, xsim

The behavior of the example below is very odd. Every file name suffix I've tried works -- except for `.js`! I've tested this on Windows, but not Linux. The behavior is the same whether run under TeXworks or with cygwin and pdflatex. It feels like a problem with Windows, but it's hard to see how.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xsim}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m!o }
{
  % This will not work. The error is
  % I can't write on file 'blather.js'
  %\str_set:Nn \l_intfig_jinfile_str { blather.js }

  % But this works!
  \str_set:Nn \l_intfig_jinfile_str { blather.xyz }

  \xsim_file_write_start:nn { \c_false_bool } \l_intfig_jinfile_str
}
{
  \xsim_file_write_stop:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here it comes

\begin{intfig}
  test test test
\end{intfig}

There it goes

\end{document}
```

In some ways, this is a follow-up to the question I asked here: [Saving the body of an environment to a file verbatim using xparse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633523/saving-the-body-of-an-environment-to-a-file-verbatim-using-xparse/633626#633626)

Also, even with an acceptable file suffix, the first character of the body is omitted in the saved file.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141408/2388  .js is in the pathext variable and so forbidden.

Comment: That explains it! Thanks.